# How to organise routes for an app with subcategories in Node.js and make them modular

Tags: node.js, express, routes, categorization

I have a basic grasp on Node.js and I'm playing with making my own app.
While I understand how routes and controllers work, I only see tutorials where all the routes have similar structure which is very simplified and rigid.

I have three requirements for my app:

1. To be able to display categories/subcategories without having to use IDs which are almost exclusively used in tutorials. The URL I would like is as follows:`www.domain.com/women/dresses/silk/dress-item-1`
2. It has to be modular so that I can add new categories and not have to define routes for all categories. For example, if I added 'shirts', I would automatically have `www.domain.com/women/shirts/...` available. Or if I added 'men', I would have `www.domain.com/men/...` available.
3. I would like to have the option of adding and stacking subcategories indefinitely in some way to get something like `www.domain.com/women/dresses/silk/long/black/dress-item-1`. I know I can use tags to define items, but I am wondering if this is possible instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a middleware to parse the uri and formulate the context based on your underlying model. And then pass it to the controller. For example, "women/dresses/silk/long/short/dress-item-1" should constitute that you are trying to take action on a resource which is hierarchical, Women has many dresses, dress has types, etc etc. If you have dynamic controller which gets added to controller list, then middleware should figure out the right controller from the list and pass the control over. Thats why I said, make use of a middleware, which will keep your code neat and structured.

Comment: Like in Express router you can add middleware as router.get("/*", common.parse, next);